# Flutter pub upgrade does not upgrade all the packages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I have a problem with the `flutter_platform_widgets` package version, and while trying to upgrade it it does not work. Is there any other way to upgrade all the packages successfuly?

The error:

```
  /C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart:269:14: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'.
  - 'PlatformButton' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_button.dart' ('/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart').
  package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_button.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
      return FlatButton(
```

Using `flutter pub upgrade`:
[image]

Comment: Try removing pubspec.lock.

Comment: Tried it, it will still keep the older version.

Comment: Unless you declare the dependencies like this `url_launcher: ^5.4.0` and don't have packages that depend on the older version when removing pubspec.lock and updating the dependencies, the newer version will be taken. For this entry without pubspec.lock the current version would be `url_launcher: 6.1.5 `. [Docs  packages](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)